# Use to use homebrew to upgrade to non-vulnerable version of git (CVE-2014-9390)

Tags: git, heroku, homebrew

Today I installed git via homebrew (`brew install git`). It downloaded git version 2.1.2.

Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/git-2.1.2.m

However, when I run `heroku apps` I get `Your version of git is 2.1.2. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.`

I thought homebrew would install the latest, patched version that addresses the recent git security vulnerability (https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/24/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x).

Also, when I run `brew update git` I get `Error: git-2.1.2 already installed`

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of brew are you running? May want to do `brew update` to make sure it's all up to date.

Comment: Ran `brew --version` got 0.9.5. Ran `brew update` got `Updated Homebrew from bece3f72 to 7015739a.` Then ran `brew upgrade git` and 2.2.1 (`https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/git-2.2.1.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz`)!! Thank you.. and you post as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure your Homebrew installation is up to date by running `brew update`. That updates both brew itself and the recipes used to install software.